# Getting 502 bad gateway error with volley android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, android-volley

I am working on a project. I am working with `oauth2` and `Volley` library. I have a login url. First I make a request to a url to get the `access_token`, `refresh_token` and `expireIn` values. Using the access_token I am hitting login url. I am able to successfully able to login at first time. But then if token expires. I am getting this below error. What am I doing wrong ?

`502 Bad Gateway error`

This is my volley request:

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, GAConstants.READUSERPROFILE_DEV_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                try {
                    MyApplication.logger.log("ReadUserProfileRequestUrl :" + GAConstants.READUSERPROFILE_DEV_URL + "ReadUserProfileError :" + new String(error.networkResponse.data,"UTF-8"));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
                NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    ConsumerAppUtils.showErrorAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.api_error));
                    Log.e("LoginActivity", "timeOuterror");
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    if (networkResponse != null && networkResponse.statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                        //Token expired
                        ConsumerAppUtils.showTokenErrorAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.accesstoken_alert));
                    } else {
                        if (networkResponse != null)
                            Log.e("LoginActivity", networkResponse.statusCode + "");
                        //Other network error
//                        ConsumerAppUtils.showErrorAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, error.getMessage());
                        if(error!=null || error.networkResponse !=null) {
                            String body = null;
                            try {
                                body = new String(error.networkResponse.data,"UTF-8");
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            ConsumerAppUtils.showErrorAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, body);
                        }
                    }
                    Log.e("LoginActivity", "serverError");
                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    if (networkResponse != null && networkResponse.statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                        //Token expired
                        ConsumerAppUtils.showTokenErrorAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.accesstoken_alert));
                    } else {
                        if(error!=null || error.networkResponse !=null) {
                            String body = null;
                            try {
                                body = new String(error.networkResponse.data,"UTF-8");
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            ConsumerAppUtils.showErrorAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, body);
                        }
                        Log.e("LoginActivity", "authFailure");
                    }
                }
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                String token = null;
                if (accessToken != null) {
                    token = accessToken;
                    Log.e("HomeScreenActivity", token);
                } else {
                    //No access token
                    ConsumerAppUtils.showTokenErrorAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.accesstoken_alert));
                }
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                params.put(OAuthConstants.AUTHORIZATION,
                        OAuthConstants.BEARER + " " + token);
                return params;
            }
        };
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this, hurlStack).add(request);
```

Comment: please check the URL you are using in the code for this request

Comment: Its working fine on server side. Only this is happening on android side. @Rizwanatta

Comment: volley library requires http or https protocols in the start of each url in the request. check the Url that's coming here has any of those?

Comment: Its starting with `https://` @Rizwanatta

Comment: check the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

To quote the definition of 502 Bad Gateway from Wikipedia: "The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and received an invalid response from the upstream server." There are many other 5xx server error messages, all of which boil down to: "The server failed to fulfill an apparently valid request.

Try this then. --> [Volley with https URLS](http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/using-android-volley-with-self-signed-certificate/)

Comment: Already added the certificate. The certificate is in .der format. I am not get SSLException also.

Comment: then only case can be your url getting some extra space etc something try to debug your Url you are getting in runtime

Comment: I am not changing the url. Its working for the first time right. But when I try to hit the url again with the same access token. I get bad gateway error.

Comment: Its perfectly working with Postman. But not in `volley`. The second request is 502 bad gateway

Comment: The server is giving 200 response. I am receiving it as 502